# Double buffering is not working properly, produces screen flicker

Tags: winapi

I'm studying WinAPI double buffering, and when I run the code below, the screen flickers too much. I think I did it right, but where is the problem?

Draw memdc1 and memdc2 to memdc, and memdc to hdc.

```
switch (iMsg)
{
case WM_CREATE:     
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientRt);
    PlaceCenterScreen(hwnd);
    SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 10, NULL);
    hMixBit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 819, 614);
    hHouseBit = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_HOUSE));
    hTigerBit = (HBITMAP)LoadBitmap(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_TIGER));
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    break;  
case WM_TIMER:
    posX += 3;
    InvalidateRgn(hwnd, NULL, true);
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); 

    memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    memdc1 = CreateCompatibleDC(memdc);
    memdc2 = CreateCompatibleDC(memdc);

    oldHouseBit = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc1, hHouseBit);
    oldTigerBit = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc2, hTigerBit);
    oldMixBit = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hMixBit);

    BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, 819, 614, memdc1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(memdc, posX, 0, 67, 47, memdc2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 819, 614, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(memdc1, oldHouseBit);
    SelectObject(memdc2, oldTigerBit);      
    SelectObject(memdc, oldMixBit);
```

Comment: You are passing `TRUE` as the last parameter to `InvalidateRgn`, which means that the background will be erased as part of `BeginPaint`. That's going to introduce another source of flicker.

Comment: Also, you should handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and return `TRUE` to prevent the default window procedure from erasing the background prior to `WM_PAINT`, which is another source of flicker. Of course you have to make sure to completely draw the whole update area in `WM_PAINT` then.

Comment: Related: For drawing, you should be using Direct2D nowadays.